# yandex-maps: Перечислить в цикле из listBoxControl все listBoxItems

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Коллеги, несколько дней назад начал заниматься с ЯндексКартами. Не так силен в JavaScript, и в частности с callback функциями... Мне бы по простому )) У меня задача, скрывать метки (Point) в зависимости от что нужно показать. Сделал фильтр для Point в ObjectManager. Фильтр включаю, выключаю, все хорошо. [Нашёл тут](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/control.ListBox-docpage/) пример с множественным выбором в listBoxControl. 3й пример. Сделал listBoxControl, в нем много listBoxItems. Оставил код до строчки 
"//Добавим отслеживание изменения признака, выбран ли пункт списка."

Всё устраивает, менюшки открываются, галочки ставятся, убираются...

Теперь мне надо свой фильтр сделать. У меня фильтр не как в примере по "аптеке" и "магазин", а по ID, где от 0-100 одни точки, с 101 по 750 другие и т.п. Т.е. строку с фильтром сформирую "руками", это проще для меня.

Хочу узнать состояние checkbox на listBoxControl (isSelected?) ... но банально не могу в цикле пробежаться по listBoxItems. Не могу узнать их количество. И следовательно к каждой обратится. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте друзья. Методом проб и ошибок разобрался! Может кому то ещё поможет. Стандартные примеры от Яндекса мне не очень понравились, в частности с фильтром.

Цикл по yandex maps listBox:

```
for (let i = 0; i < listBoxControl.getAll().length; i++) {
    if (listBoxControl.getAll()[i].isSelected()){
        alert(listBoxControl.getAll()[i].data.get('content'));
    }
}
```